# MVC 4 Date (custom format) validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

In my application there's a requirement that date are entered like this : d-MMM-yyyy
I can render that just fine like this :

@model : 
`[DataMember] public DateTime SomeDateField { get; set; }`

@View :
`@Html.EditorFor(model => model.SomeDateField)`
`@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SomeDateField)`

EditorTemplate: DateTime.cshtml
`@model DateTime`
`@Html.TextBox("", (Model.Equals(DateTime.MinValue) ? string.Empty : Model.ToString("d-MMM-yyyy")), new { @class = "date" })`

Shared._Layout.cshtml
`$(".date").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'd-MMM-yyyy' });`

I'm not sure why but there's something going wrong with the client-side validation on IE9 and FireFox. When leaving the field (even if it's valid) a red box is drawn around the input-field but no validation-message is shown. I'm not sure where the problem is but I'm pretty sure I'm not the first to encounter it. I've searched stackoverflow but didn't find a solution (yet).

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Jurjen.

Comment: Try using the `DisplayFormat` attribute on your `DateTime` property, does that help? `[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d MMM yyyy}")]`

Comment: no, that doesn't help, already tried that. even with :
`[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d-MMM-yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]`
No problems in chrome though, just in IE/Firefox (haven't tried safari yet)